# Is [[unlikely]] possible with loops?

Tags: c++, c++20

I use `[[likely]]` / `[[unlikely]]` on heavily frequented ifs. I recently had a loop which where the condition is rarely met, i.e. the loop is rarely enterted or repeated.
Is it possible to have a `[[unlikely]]` on a loop ? On en.cppreference.com I find nothing about that.

Comment: You can rewrite loop with `if` statement

Comment: Yes, and with _gotos_ !

Comment: I do not see how `while(true) { if( condition ) break; ... }` is related to `goto`

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There is even [an example of it on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely):

```
constexpr double cos(double x) noexcept {
    constexpr long long precision{16LL};
    double y{};
    for (auto n{0LL}; n < precision; n += 2LL) [[likely]]
        y += pow(x, n) / (n & 2LL ? -fact(n) : fact(n));
    return y;
}
```

You apply the attribute to the start of the loop body.

Comment: Interestingly, the standard is worded in such a way that `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` are applied to a label or statement, so in this case it is syntactically part of the `y += ...` statement rather than the `for` header. Indeed you can annotate any random statement as `[[likely]] std::cout << "foo\n";`, although of course it would be daft to actually do it when there's no control flow decision to be made. See [dcl.attr.likelihood] in C++20 for reference.

Comment: Offtopic: implementation of `cos` in this cppreference example it terrible. Many newbies implement this in same manner and then asking question on SO why it doesn't work.